# jQuery AutoComplete does not refresh when new data entered into text box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-autocomplete

I type the words "How do" and it pops up a list, and returns matches on "How do". I stop for a second, and continue typing " I make a sandwich?" for instance.

It pops up on the "How do" but does not refresh the results when I continue typing.

How do I get it to refresh once data has been typed more?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#Query").autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("Find", "Controller") %>', { minChars: 3, delay : 400 });
});
```

Comment: jQuery has changed since I've asked this question, so this will not be relevent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed some of the settings in the .js file and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Others that find this page via Google won't have any idea what setting you changed in the js file. Could you update your answer with more specifics?

Comment: It's been a year, and I no longer remember. Sorry. :)

Comment: Really? Two years later?